# Variables in python with pynput

Tags: python, bots, pynput

So I'm making a program that types a number using pynput, then adds 1 to that number, hits enter, and keeps going. However, when it hits 10, the program stops working. Here's my code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

keyboard = Controller()

#Example keys:
#keyboard.press('a')
#keyboard.release('a')

#Set the variables for the first number:
number = 8

#Define the press release button, for simple use. 
def press_release_char(char):
    keyboard.press(char)
    keyboard.release(char)

#Set start delay:
time.sleep(3)

while number<100:
    press_release_char(str(number))
    press_release_char(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(number)
    number += 1
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

It's because string representation of `10` actually consists of **two** characters: `1` and then `0`, so you must account for that accordingly. Basically you should loop over string representation of your `number` and send all digits separately, so replace your:

```
press_release_char(str(number))
```

with more generic approach:

```
for c in str(number): press_release_char(c)
```

and you should be good for any number, no matter how many digits you have. In fact the same loop can be used to send any sequence of characters.

Comment: Small gripe - if you don't need the index, just `[press_release_char(c) for c in str(number)]`.  Also a list comprehension is not needed here since you are not capturing the output.  Just `for c in str(number): press_release_char(c)` would work.

Comment: Yep, that's a bit over-engeneering. Corrected.

Comment: @DuckMan if your problem is solved, please mark answer as accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers